# PHP 'While' within a ForEach loop pulling from SQL DataBase

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, foreach, while-loop

I have a little table being duplicated several times based on the number of entries there are in my SQL Database, which let's say is about colours. These tables will go one place to the right with each new entry. Within that, I now want, within each entry, to be able to automate an output for a few fields. For example, a single table entry might be 'reds' and now I want to display the different shades of red, i.e. 'shade1', 'shade2', 'shade3', 'shade4' from that, and then the next entry might be 'yellows' and I would want it to display as many yellows there were added, i.e. 'shade1', 'shade2'. My code is like this:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM colours");
        $stmt->execute();
        $colours = $stmt->fetchALL();

    if($colours){
    $i = 1;

        foreach ($colours as $key => $colour) {
            $coloursrow1 .='<table >
                <tr><th>' . "<b>{$colour['colour']}</b>" . '</th></tr>
                <tr><td>' . "<img src='{$colour['shade1']}' />" . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>' . "<img src='{$colour['shade2']}' />" . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>' . "<img src='{$colour['shade3']}' />" . '</td></tr>
                <tr><td>' . "<img src='{$colour['shade4']}' />" . '</td></tr>
            </table>';
            $i++;
        }   
    }
?>
```

And I wondered if instead of all the lines like `<tr><td>' . "<img src='../colours/reds/shade1.jpg' />" . '</td></tr>`, I could put something like

```
if($colours){
$i = 1; $x = 1;

    foreach ($colours as $key => $colour) {
        $coloursrow1 .='<table >
            <tr><th>' . "<b>{$colour['colour']}</b>" . '</th></tr>';
    }
        while ($x < 6) {
            '<tr><td>' . "<img src='{$colour['shade$x']}' />" . '</td></tr>';
            $x++;
        }
    foreach ($colours as $key => $colour) {
        '</table>';
        $i++;
    }   
}
```

So that it would grab and output them automatically and also giving me the ability to put a cap on how many can be output.

I tried different ways to accomplish this, but I just keep hitting dead ends. I must be doing something wrong(?)

Comment: `$colour` is only in scope within the `foreach()`, so bracketing the `while()` will not work as you anticipate.

Comment: I now see how much sense that makes, but when I try to include the `while ()` into the `foreach ($colours as colour) {}`, it processes for 30seconds and then time-outs with an error. I am not understanding the problem in that either.

Comment: Probably because the `$i++` got dropped and it's an infinite loop (30 max execution seconds).

Comment: Ah! That explains a few things to me as I have had this occur before. How would I set a cap to that in this situation then? Put the whole thing in another `while ($i < 8) {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like it would be something like this, since `PDO::fetchAll()` returns an empty array or false on error. So just iterate over that set directly. Also, the array access is wrong, it should be `{$colour['shade'.$x]}`.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM colours");
$stmt->execute();
$colours = $stmt->fetchALL();

foreach ($colours as $colour) {
    $coloursrow1 .= "<table><tr><th><b>{$colour['colour']}</b></th></tr>";

    $x = 1;

    while ($x < 6) {
        $coloursrow1 .= "<tr><td><img src='{$colour['shade'.$x]}' /></td></tr>";
        $x++;
    }

    $coloursrow1 .= '</table>';
}
```

Comment: Bravo! Perfect fix. In addition to my original error, I can now see that I completely failed to recognise that I was required to put  `$coloursrow1 .= "` in each fresh row of code being added. Thank you very much for going through this with me, Jared.